# How to display large size image using UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

In my application, I have one large size image 800 x 2000. And I want to display this image in UIImageView, also this image is scrollable.

I tried this below code.

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"About_CVR_Detail"];
self.aImgView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, Screen_Width,img.size.height);
self.aImgView.image=img;
self.aScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(Screen_Width, self.aImgView.frame.size.height);
```

And Also ty this one also:

```
self.aScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"About_CVR_Detail"]];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll the image on both Horizontal and vertical oritation, you can do as danh said.

But if you want only one oritation to scroll , you should set the fixed width or height ,and to keep the ratio, also, should calcualte the other length.

For example:

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.aImgView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, Screen_Width, Screen_Width * img.size.height / img.size.width);
self.aImgView.image=img;

[self.aScrollView addSubview:self.aImgView];
self.aScrollView.contentSize= self.aImgView.frame.size;
```

The code above allow you to scroll only on vertical oritation.

Comment: Thank u so so much. This solution is Awesome. :) This is the one that I want

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the image view as a child of the scroll view.  Also, you can simplify the layout by using the image's size (which sets up the image view in `initWithImage`, whose bounds can be used for the scroll view contentSize)..

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"About_CVR_Detail"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

[self.aScrollView addSubview:imageView];
self.aScrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size;
```